Manga where the main character gets summoned to another world and trapped in a dungeon
I'm looking for a manga where he gets sent to a dungeon for having a weak healing ability but finds a bottle in a chest that gives him the opposite of his ability (I believe it was called erosion)

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Are there any other details you remember that you could [edit] in? Was this manga in colour or was it black and white? When and where did you read it? Can you remember anything else about the main character; what they looked like, etc?

Is this Nito's Lazy Foreign World Syndrome...?

Hidako Masamune is a high school student who suffers from continuous bullying by his classmates. Becoming tired of it all, he decides to commit suicide, but instead he is transported to another world along with all his classmates. When they arrive, they find that they now possess amazing abilities but he was only granted the status of a "healer," the weakest skill of all. The king decides to get rid of him by transporting him to another far away place, but not before Hidako swears revenge against the king, the kingdom, and all of his classmates.

As noted in the summary, the main character, Hidaka Masamune, is summoned to a kingdom in another world, along with a bunch of other students, but is subsequently cast out into a dungeon when they discover he's 'only' a healer.
In that dungeon, he finds a room with some treasure chests in it. One of the chests has a magic potion in it called 'God of Revenge's Mischief' which enables him to reverse the effect of his healing power and turn it into a deadly attack called 'Waves of Erosion.'




